# When to perform parameter type checking in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For the most part, the library I'm developing is going to be consumed internally by one or more projects.  With that in mind, should I add logic that performs type checking on all parameters for functions I write, on some parameters or none?  To do selective type checking, I feel, would create an inconsitent feel to the API, to do it for all parameters would bloat the code, and to do it for none could lead to error messages that aren't helpful.  Any guidance as to why or why not would be appreciated.

Comment: _"is going to be consumed a single internally by one or more projects."_: Please clarify, I can't make heads or tails about that line.

Comment: I'm sure there's **many** opinions about this, but I try to leave type-checking out in as many cases as possible unless there's an absolute necessity for a certain type. I think the only place I do it is for passing functions, so I know I can call them. Just try using `===` for equality as it will not attempt to coerce types and will make sure two values are the same value and type. I like to think that if the user (might be yourself) isn't going to use the API correctly, they can expect weird results. Like Zeta said, documentation is important and can help prevent problems

Comment: @Cerbrus Sorry about that.  I blame the grammar error on fatigue and late hour (it's past midnight for me).

Comment: I assume you mean _"used internally by..."_? ;-)

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the feedback.  I originally went with some verbose type checking logic, but feel like, as Zeta mentioned, that documention is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is important that you document your API, even if it's only for internal use. It comes in handy if you need your code some years later.

In this documentation you can tell the user what type the parameters should be. An often used tool for documentation is [doxygen](http://doxygen.org):

```
/**
* \brief Converts a string into a DummyObject
* \param str should be a valid string
*/
function str_to_dummy(str) {

}

/**
* \brief Converts an object into a DummyObject
* \param jsobj should be an object which contains at least
*        the following attibutes: 'height','length', 'size'
* \example json_to_dummy({'height': 12,'length': 15,'size': 11});
*/
function json_to_dummy(jsobj) {

}
```

Keep in mind that the user will experience an error message either way, either:

```
Parameter 'o' must be an object with attribute 'height'
```

or

```
ReferenceError: o.height is undefined
```

While it is nice to get a more verbose error, it often isn't necessary if you document your API correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it all comes down to how well you want to handle errors in your library. Can you live with the fact that someone passes you arguments of invalid type (even though, I'm assuming, documentation states clearly what he/she should pass)? If you're ok with that I would skip type checking to save on library size.

After all it's only client-side javascript if someone wants to tamper with it he will. There's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you (almost) always should check or cast function parameters.
I just had smth. like this yesterday:

```
foo("1");  

function foo(myVar)  
{  
  return myVar+2;  
}
```

So you should be careful. I believe it is a good reason.